# Invalid syntax in else: python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name() == "us_city_pop_gt_10k_albersaea":
            layer = lyr
        self.dlg.Statecombo.clear()

        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self.dlg, "Layer Name","Load us_city_pop_gt_10k_albersaea layer and  try again")
```

I am giving conditionals that if a layer name exists do this, else give a warning message. But it shows an error "Invalid Syntax". Please help me in figuring out this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self.dlg.Statecombo.clear()` is "ending" your if  (because it is not indented correctly) statement, so "else" doesn't know what the condition is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just have another statement *splitting* the `if` and the `else` of your conditional statement. Either you have an indentation error and `self.dlg.Statecombo.clear()` is intended to be within the `if` statement, or you have to move that statement, as it is ending your `if` statement and causing `else` to make no sense.